# Calling a closure from a task in Rust

Tags: rust

Anyone knows if there's a way around the following error in Rust?

Or at least explain what the error means? The docs say the [Send](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/kinds/trait.Send.html) trait has no implementors...

```
fn f1() {
    println!("f1");
}

fn main() {
    let f2 = || {
        println!("f2");
    };
    spawn(proc() {
        f1();
        f2();  // error: the trait `core::kinds::Send` is not implemented for the type `||`
    });
}
```

This is with

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 0.13.0-nightly (adb44f53d 2014-10-12 00:07:15 +0000)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Send`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/kinds/trait.Send.html) is a **kind**, which is a trait that is automatically implemented by the compiler on types that have a particular characteristic. `Send`, for instance, describes "types able to be transferred across task boundaries". The main reason why a type would not implement `Send` is if the type contains borrowed pointers.

Closure types capture their environment by reference, i.e. using the equivalent of borrowed pointers, therefore they don't implement `Send`. `proc`s, on the other hand, capture their environment by "move", i.e. values referenced inside the `proc` are moved into the `proc`, which means you can't use the value after the `proc` is defined. Because they capture their environment by move, `proc`s own all the data they captured, so they implement `Send` and you can send them to another `proc`. However, `proc`s also have another important limitation: you can't call them more than once.

Unboxed closures are a new feature still in development that provide a solution for these problems. Here's an example using unboxed closures:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures, overloaded_calls)]

fn f1() {
    println!("f1");
}

fn main() {
    let f2 = |&:| {
        println!("f2");
    };
    spawn(proc() {
        f1();
        f2();
        f2(); // f2 can be called again
    });
}
```

`|&:|` defines a closure that implements [`Fn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), which means that the `call` method is invoked on an immutable reference. Since the closure doesn't capture anything, it implements `Send`, and since calling the closure doesn't consume it (which `|:|` would, because such closures implement [`FnOnce`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html), in which `call_once` is invoked on a by-value `self`), it can be called more than once.

If the closure needs to mutate its environment, you can also define the closure like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut f2 = |&mut:| {
        println!("f2");
    };
    spawn(proc() {
        f1();
        f2();
        f2();
    });
}
```

`|&mut:|` makes the closure implement [`FnMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), and `let mut` is required to be able to invoke `call_mut`.